# Generalized Gaussian Decomposition

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, cluster-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected complex semisimple Lie group. Let $H$ be a maximal torus of $G$, let $W$ be the Weyl group of $G$, and let $N_\pm$ be a pair of opposite maximal unipotent subgroups. For each simple root $\alpha_i$ we define a Lie group homomorphism $\varphi_i:SL_2\rightarrow G$ in the obvious way. Define $\overline{s}_i$ to be the image of $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ under $\varphi_i$, so it is a lift of the Weyl group generator $s_i$. It is a fact that by imposing the condition that $\overline{w}:=\overline{s}_i\overline{u}$ whenever $l(w)=l(u)+1$, one can unambiguously find a lift $\overline{w}$ for each Weyl group element $w$.

In Fomin and Zelevinsky's paper on double Bruhat cells they say that for any element $x\in G$ one can write $x=x^-a\overline{w}x^+$, with $x^\pm\in N_\pm$, $a\in H$ and $w\in W$, and they claim that $a$ and $w$ are uniquely determined by $x$. This is kind of a generalized version of Gaussian decomposition that works for all group elements.

I am able to see the existence of such an expression and the uniqueness of $w$, but how do I prove that $a$ is unique? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you able to see the isomorphism $U\times H = B$?

Comment: Yes. How do you relate that to this problem?